# Navigating inside Device Manager of windows 8 using only keyboard to enable Laptop Touchpad

Tags: windows

My laptop touchpad was annnoying so i disabled it in the device manager. Now my curiosity is

> How to enable touchpad using device manager without using external
>   mouse && using only the keyboard.

Please suggest alternatives that doesnt include installing softwares or touchpad drivers.

**I have already done following steps:**

- ***windows key + x***
- selected device manager using ***up/down* arrow**.
- for **selecting mice and other pointers** i tried and failed in following keys

  - **up/down arrow**
  - **alt+up, alt+down**.etc

Comment: I think you're looking for the right arrow.

Answer (score -1):

**windows + X** to open device manager

**TAB** to jump into device tree

**arrow down** to go to mice and other pointing devices

**arrow right** to open mice and other pointing devices

**arrow down** to select your device

**menu key** to open context menu

**arrow down** to select *activate device*

Comment: The question is completely off-topic and so is the answer.